# Border around text range

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a chat application using WPF. Text messages are added to Rich textboxes created **at runtime** and these boxes are added to a Stack panel.

I need to have **different colored borders** for messages from different users.

How can I set border at runtime around these messages?

Comment: Create a User class that have a Color property, create a Message class that references a User and use the Message.User.Color to set the Border.BorderBrush

Answer (score 0):

You can use Border() :) ie:

```
Border b = new Border()
{
    BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80)),
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 0, 1, 2),
    CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(1, 1, 1, 5)
};
```

You could have your StackPanel as a placeholder and add to it at runtime. sp.Children.Add( b );

EDIT: A sample:

```
void Main()
{
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Border b = new Border()
        {
            BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(
            i % 2 == 0
            ? Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80)
            : Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x0, 0x0)
            ),
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 0, 1, 2),
            CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(1, 1, 1, 5),
            Child = new RichTextBox()
        };
        sp.Children.Add(b);
    }

    new Window { Content = sp }.ShowDialog();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cetin, but this does not work and I have no idea why. This does not show a border at all. :(

Comment: Actually I have tried that in Linqpad before sending and it worked for me (added the namespaces). And, I am also using the same code, slightly modified, in a real world Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the border brush property, any control that has border has this property for example if you want to add border color to a button you write the following:

```
myButton.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(a: 255, r: 204, g: 204, b: 204));
```

I hope this solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Fadl. But I'm looking for a way to have border only around text. And strings do not have Border brush property.